# How to collect SIP messages in android studio?

Tags: java, android, call, sip, telephonymanager

I'm developing an mobile app with 'TelephonyManager' and I wanted to know if its possible to colelct SIP message (sip header) with this librarie ?

I've already tested some methods but I don't see how to get the SIP message

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "MISSING PERMISSION!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
tm.showInCallScreen(false);
info = intent.getDataString();
//read the SIP message before accept ringing call//
tm.acceptRingingCall();
```

Comment: your post is unclear, are you trying to answer an incoming SIP call?

Comment: I want to know how can I get a sip header from a incoming gsm call @marmor